# My TimerTask not running

Tags: android, timertask

for some reason my timer is running only once:

Code:

```
int i = 0;
private void startTimer() {


    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("DTAG","K1");

            if(preferences.getBoolean(IS_RUNNING_KEY, false))
            {
                Log.d("DTAG","K2");
                final int k = i++;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timeCounter.setText(""+k);
                        Log.d("DTAG","K: "+k);
                    }
                });
            } else {

                Log.d("DTAG","K3");
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();

            }
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 1000);

}
```

Log:

```
04-12 16:47:32.333 3079-3684/com.michlind.nanytime D/DTAG: K1
04-12 16:47:32.334 3079-3684/com.michlind.nanytime D/DTAG: K2
04-12 16:47:32.338 3079-3079/com.michlind.nanytime D/DTAG: K: 0
```

Comment: in API the description for schedule(task,1000) is: `Schedule a task for single execution`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour of `schedule(TimerTask, long)`. From the documentation

> Schedule a task for single execution after a specified delay.

Try using `scheduleAtFixedRate` instead.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))

Answer (score 4):

May be try reading documentation to understand it better [Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

The function you are using

```
 Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)
```

Schedule a task for single execution after a specified delay.

Use

```
Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

for scheduling a task for repeated fixed-rate execution after a specific delay has passed i.e. in your case

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call *schedule* method with two params. First is for how much it must wait to start, second is the interval between executions:

```
 // schedule the timer, after the first 1000ms the TimerTask will run every 1s
 timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
```